# How to run a.py file in python cmd?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm a newbie to python, so I just installed python27 on my win8 machine and set the path for C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts.

Now I want to execute a small .py file, so at the shell (python cmd) I type:

```
python "c:\python27\gtos.py"

  File "<stdin>", line 1

  python "c:\python27\gtos.py"
                               ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help is appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Treat it like a module:

   ```
   import file
   ```

   This is good because it's secure, fast, and maintainable. Code gets reused as it's supposed to be done. Most Python libraries run using multiple methods stretched over lots of files. Highly recommended. Note that your import should not include the .py extension at the end.
2. Use the exec command:

   ```
   execfile('file.py')
   ```

   But this is likely to go wrong very often and is kind of hacky.
3. Spawn a shell process:

   ```
   import subprocess
   import sys

   subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'file.py'])
   ```

   Use when desperate.

Comment: Thanks Alex: But I'm not sure, I understand :( you'll have to dumb it down for me. I tried typing import gtos.py and I get the same syntax error. Maybe I'm missing an interpreter or something!!! what I type I get syntax error!!!

Comment: Some advice for SO: when you read an answer, read the whole answer- you learn alot more looking at explanations and other solutions. I said when importing a file, do not use the file extension. :)

Comment: THAT DID IT (no extension). THANKS ALEX!

Comment: the 2nd and 3rd options are much more rare than the 1st (`import module`). There is even no `execfile()` in Python 3 any more. And `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'module.py'])` could be used instead of `os.system()`.

Comment: Don't use `shell=True` unless it is necessary (and it is not here).