# How to run a file from the body of a program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the python command to run a py-file.?

For example, in my index.py file how would i launch start.py.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960959/how-to-run-a-py-file-in-python-cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `index.py`, simply use `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(["python", "start.py"])
```